# Kubernetes Kops and Federation

Tags: kubernetes, kops

Has anyone had any success getting kops and federation to work together?

We've tried to set up a couple of clusters using kops and have created the correct contexts.

However, when we try to join one cluster to another, the dns names used by kops are incompatible with those that kubefed requires.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried kubefed, e.g. as demonstrated https://gist.github.com/arun-gupta/02f534c7720c8e9c9a875681b430441a?

Although I think to be really HA you should not install the federation components in either federated clusters, but in a third cluster, in a separate region. Eg

- cluster 1: **us-east-1**
- cluster 2: **us-west-2**
- federation cluster
  (federates clusters 1 and 2, and perhaps other sets of clusters): one
  of **ca-central-1, us-east-2, or europe-west-3** depending on your
  requirements)

Comment: Appreciate the comment, I'm sure it works much better now than then :-D